# Prove that $a^{2^n}=1 \mod 2^{n+2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to prove that

$$a^{2^n}\equiv 1 \pmod {2^{n+2}}$$

I tried induction but could not get it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You need some hypothesis on $a$, e.g., it's false for $a=2$.

Comment: $$0^{2^n}\neq 1\pmod{2^{n+2}}\ldots$$

Comment: isn't this false? take $n=1, \quad a=2$. Then $4 = {1} \mod {8}$ which is false? Or am I missing something

Answer (score 8):

$$a^{2^n}-1=(a-1)(a+1)(a^{2}+1)\cdots(a^{2^{n-1}}+1)$$

If $a$ is odd then each term in the factorisation is even (**i.e.** divisible by $2$), there are $n+1$ such terms hence $a^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$. Since either $a-1$ or $a+1$ is a multiple of $4$, we have an additional factor of $2$, therefore $a^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a$ is odd! And note we have to start at $n=1$. The base step is the familiar fact that the square of an odd number is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.  We now deal with the induction step.

Suppose that we know the result for $k$. So $a^{2^k}=1+b2^{k+2}$. Square both sides. On the left, we get $a^{2^{k+1}}$. On the right, we get the extra factor of $2$ from the middle term in the expansion $(s+t)^2=s^2+2st+t^2$.