# Show that $x^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{32}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $x$ is odd, then $x^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{32}$.

I tried using the expansion $$(2k+1)^8 = 256 k^8+1024 k^7+1792 k^6+1792 k^5+1120 k^4+448 k^3+112 k^2+16 k+1,$$ but I don't see how that helps. Is there an easier way?

How would we prove in general that $x^{{2^k}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k+2}}$ if $x$ is odd?

Comment: A special case of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/313501/11619).

Comment: And with the edit of OP it became a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 9):

All but the last three terms are divisible by $32$, and $112\equiv 16\pmod{32}$, so the whole thing is congruent to $16+16+1\equiv1\pmod{32}$ if $k$ is odd. If $k$ is even, every term is a multiple of $32$ except the final $1$.

Comment: How do you know it isn't $32+16+1 = 49$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: because $k^2+k$ is always even

Comment: @Puzzled417: Because if $k$ is odd, the three terms reduce mod $32$ to $16,16$, and $1$, and if $k$ is even, they reduce to $0,0$, and $1$. There is no value of $k$ for which they reduce to $0,16$, and $1$.

Comment: How do we prove this in general?

Comment: @Puzzled417: Prove what in general? What I said in my previous comment?

Comment: How would we prove in general that $x^{{2^k}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k+2}}$ if $x$ is odd?

Comment: @Puzzled417: I’ve not checked the details thoroughly, but I suspect that you can do it by showing that $2^{k+2}$ is a divisor of $\binom{2^k}{\ell}2^\ell$ for $3\le\ell\le 2^k$.