# A question in elementary number theory related to proving a congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was trying to prove the congruence $ a^{2^n} \equiv 1 ( mod 2^{n+2} )$  but couldn't.

Then I found this question on MSE ->[Prove that $a^{2^n}=1 \mod 2^{n+2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313501/prove-that-a2n-1-mod-2n2).

> The 2 answers which are mentioned here assumes a to be odd. Can someone please explain why a cannot be even and if it can be even how to deal with that problem.  Also the question in my assignment doesn't assumes a to be odd.

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: If $a$ is even, the left-hand side is even but the right-hand side is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David G. Stork](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210401/david-g-stork)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533700/a-question-in-elementary-number-theory-related-to-proving-a-congruence#comment7267714_3533700) states

> If $a$ is even, the left-hand side is even but the right-hand side is odd.

In particular, you have

$$a^{2^n} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{n+2}} \implies 2^{n+2} \mid a^{2^n} - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

With $a$ being even, then $a^{2^n} - 1$ is odd, so $2^{n+2}$ can't divide into it.